# Looping in if statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I am new to java/programming and I thought a good way to learn was making a simple text RPG game. 
Im on a class file where you can hire workers to mine ore for you. Basically, I take 2000 gold from the user, and randomize a number between 1-5 10 times and they get ore based on the number 10 times. (e.g, 1 is copper, 4 is gold)

this is what I have so far, when i run it it takes my gold but only gives me 1 ore when it really should give me 10, any help?
edit: sorry forgot to mention i had int x = 0;at the top

```
if ((input.input.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) && inventory.goldCoins >= 2000) {
    System.out.println("You have hired Sanchez for $2000!");
    inventory.goldCoins -= 2000;

    do {
        int workerOre = (int )(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        if (workerOre == 1) {
            inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
            menu.start();
        } else if (workerOre == 2) {
            inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
            menu.start();
        } else if (workerOre == 3) {
            inventory.addInventory("Steel Ore");
            menu.start();
        } else if (workerOre == 4) {
            inventory.addInventory("Gold Ore");
            menu.start();
        } else if (workerOre == 5) {
            inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
        }
        x++;
    } while (x < 10);
    System.out.println("Sanchez has finished his shift and the ore has been added to your inventory!");
} else if ((input.input.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) && inventory.goldCoins < 2000) {
    System.out.println("You do not have enough money!");
    worker();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that you never initialized x, so it is just equal to some garbage value. Try adding `int x = 0` before your do-while loop.

I also noticed that you are calling `menu.start()` after adding the Ore to your inventory, is there a chance that your program never gets back into the loop?

You will need to use a `break` to jump out of the switch statement after it has identified the case, secondly you can add a `default` to the end of the switch that will be used if there is ever a time that case 1 through case 4 are not satisfied. Ex:

```
switch(ore)
{
    case 1: inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
        break;
    case 2: inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
        break;
    case 3: inventory.addInventory("Steel Ore");
        break;
    case 4: inventory.addInventory("Gold Ore");
        break;
    default: inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i had int x = 0;at the top

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize `x`.

Just add `int x = 0` before you start the `do...while`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mineOre();
}

public void mineOre() {
    int ore = (int) Math.random() * 5 + 1;
    switch (ore) {
        case 1: inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
        case 2: inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
        case 3: inventory.addInventory("Steel Ore");
        case 4: inventory.addInventory("Gold Ore");
        case 5: inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
    }
    menu.start();
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked, but it gave me 5 of the exact ores in the cases. I want it to be random, so maybe like 3 copper 1 steel 1 gold etc, how is that possibe? also why did it give 5 instad of 10?

Comment: The randomizer might not be perfect or your inventory adding system system might not be complete. Try replacing the inventory adders with System.out.println();'s for testing, and see what the output is. Play around with it, there might be some bugs to fix.